# Is this a good implementation of digital signature with timestamp?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, sha-256, dsa, xor

[image]

Is this a good practice ?.

How good or bad is this compared to appending a timestamp to the actual data and hashing it as represented below.
**`Signature = sign(sha256( File + Timestamp ))`**

Comment: What is happening with the data? The timestamp is worth little if I create it.  Whereas the signature is worth little if I have to send my private key to a server (which is a [TSA](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3161)).  Hashing the time separately (or not) shouldn't make any difference for a good hash.  Why is XOR tagged?

Comment: @ModalNest The above diagram is an abstract concept. Consider this scenario; the user will send a file to the server. assuming the server is trusted and time is generated by an atomic clock, The file is signed along with the timestamp and returns it. The signature is generated with the server's private key in an HSM. XOR tagged because there are some security considerations with concatenating two hashes. It can be good or bad based on the implementation and use case. I'm not sure if it is okay to use xor in my specific setup.

Comment: Ok, I suppose I thought the user would be signing.  You've not asked any question about XOR though, you've asked (and given a diagram) about concatenating 2 hash outputs.  Concatenating 1  and 2 is '12'.  XORing 1 and 2 is '3'.

Comment: Hint for this homework: find an attack on $\text{Signature}=\text{sign}(\text{sha256}(\text{File}\mathbin\|\text{Timestamp}))$ allowing to transform a file signed 2020-12-24
(1608790765 seconds since 1970-01-01, where 1608790765 is the 168790765 in the illustration with an extra zero to make the date contemporaneous) into a different file signed circa 1989-04-17. Does that work for the system illustrated, with $\text{Signature}=\text{sign}(\text{sha256}(\text{sha256}(\text{File})\mathbin\|\text{sha256}(\text{Timestamp})))$ ?

Comment: This is not to say the question's system is satisfactory: the whole timestamping (except perhaps the file hash) should be in the HSM.

Comment: That is why one needs delimiters to overcome such attacks.

Comment: Thank you for your comments